# Create a new index with field property marked as 'not-analyzed' in Kibana Dev Tools

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

How to create in the Kibana dev-tools a new Elasticsearch index and define one of its text field properties a **not-analyzed** ?

I know the command to create a new index is:

```
PUT /myNewIndexName
```

but I want one of the properties in the document to be **not-analyzed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `analyzed` value is from <7.X, the current approach to doing that is to use a `keyword` field - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/keyword.html

```
PUT myNewIndexName
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field_name": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```